# Python: TypeError Cannot concatenate 'str and 'list' objects

Tags: python, binary-tree, typeerror

I'm writing a python script to create a binary tree, and I keep receiving a `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects` when using the professor's example code to print 'branches' of the tree based on position of the node:

```
    def print_node(self, depth):
        print('---' * depth + self.key)
        if self.left_child is not None:
            self.left_child.print_node(depth + 1)
        if self.right_child is not None:
            self.right_child.print_node(depth + 1)
```

However, I modified code for a binary tree I found else where, and it still doesn't work, but its also not throwing the `TypeError` I get when using the professor's code. As such, I'm confused what the issue is that is causing the error to be thrown.

Full Code:

```
class BinaryTreeNode():
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None

    def print_node(self, depth):
        print('---' * depth + str(self.key))
        if self.left_child is not None:
            self.left_child.print_node(depth + 1)
        if self.right_child is not None:
            self.right_child.print_node(depth + 1)

    def insert_node(self, newNode):
        if newNode == self.key:
            return False
        elif newNode < self.key:
            if self.left_child:
                return self.left_child.insert_node(newNode)
            else:
                self.left_child = BinaryTreeNode(newNode)
                return True
        else:
            if self.right_child:
                return self.right_child.insert_node(newNode)
            else:
                self.right_child = BinaryTreeNode(newNode)
                return True

class BinaryTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, k):
        if self.root:
            return self.root.insert(k)
        else:
            self.root = BinaryTree(k)
            return True

    def print_tree(self):
        self.root.print_node(k)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = BinaryTree()
    tree.insert(5)
    tree.insert(28)
    tree.insert(17)
    tree.insert(22)
    tree.insert(229)
    tree.insert(222)
    tree.insert(2)
    tree.print_tree()
```

The expected result of this should be the binary tree printed something like this:

```
5
---2
---28
-----17
-------22
----------21
------229
--------222
```

**EDIT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Programming Projects/BinaryTree.py", line 48, in <module>
    tree.print_tree()
  File "G:/Programming Projects/BinaryTree.py", line 37, in print_tree
    self.root.print_node(0)
  File "G:/Programming Projects/BinaryTree.py", line 10, in print_node
    print('---' * depth + self.key)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

Modified "working" code:

```
class Node():

    def __init__(self,val):
        self.value = val
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None

    def print_node(self, depth):
        print('---' * depth + self.value)
        if self.left_child is not None:
            self.left_child.print_node(depth + 1)
        if self.right_child is not None:
            self.right_child.print_node(depth + 1)

    def _insert(self,data):
        if data == self.value:
            return False
        elif data < self.value:
            if self.left_child:
                return self.left_child._insert(data)
            else:
                self.left_child = Node(data)
                return True
        else:
            if self.right_child:
                return self.right_child._insert(data)
            else:
                self.right_child = Node(data)
                return True

    def _inorder(self):
        if self:
            if self.left_child:
                self.left_child._inorder()
            print(self.value)
            if self.right_child:
                self.right_child._inorder()



class Tree():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self,data):
        if self.root:
            return self.root._insert(data)
        else:
            self.root = Node(data)
            return True
    def inorder(self):
        if self.root is not None:
            return self.root._inorder()
        else:
            return False

if __name__=="__main__":
    a = Tree()
    a.insert(5)
    a.insert(28)
    a.insert(17)
    a.insert(22)
    a.insert(229)
    a.insert(222)
    a.insert(2)
    a.inorder()
```

Comment: You'll need to give us the full traceback, as well as the code that will reproduce the exception. From a cursory reading, I'm guessing `self.key` is a list object, but we can't see how `self.key` is set, nor do we have the traceback to show us what line the exception is coming from or how Python got there.

Comment: I edited to provide the full traceback as well as the second iteration that runs without the `TypeError`

Comment: Please don't use an image; a traceback is still text. Screenreaders can't read that text out, nor can we copy and paste the traceback to analyse it. Some networks block imgur images altogether.

Comment: Why are you using `newNode = []` and not `k` to insert? You are explicitly setting `key` to a list with that.

Comment: Are you sure your `BinaryTreeNode.insert_node()` code is complete? For `newNode > self.key` *nothing happens*, there is no `else` branch there inserting the value in to the right subtree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BinaryTree.insert()` method has a bug in it:

```
def insert(self, k):
    if self.root:
        return self.root.insert_node(newNode)
    else:
        self.root = BinaryTreeNode(newNode)
        return True
```

This code *ignores* the `k` argument and uses the global `newNode` instead. That value is set to a list:

```
newNode = []
```

So this creates nodes where the `key` attribute is set to an empty list, which breaks the assumption of the `print_node()` function that `self.key` is always a string.

To make the code work, you need to make *two* changes:

- Fix insert to use `k` instead of `newNode`:

  ```
  def insert(self, k):
      if self.root:
          return self.root.insert_node(k)
      else:
          self.root = BinaryTreeNode(k)
          return True
  ```
- Either convert `self.key` to a string before concatenating to `'---' * depth`, or only use string values in your tree. Converting to string is more flexible:

  ```
  print('---' * depth + str(self.key))
  ```

Note that `BinaryTreeNode.insert_node()` method is also incomplete; there is no code handling insertion into the *right* child tree; only the `newNode == self.key` and `newNode < self.key` cases are handled, the `newNode > self.key` case is omitted, and presumably `True` should be returned if a new node is added:

```
def insert_node(self, newNode):
    if newNode == self.key:
        return False
    elif newNode < self.key:
        if self.left_child:
            return self.left_child.insert_node(newNode)
        else:
            self.left_child = BinaryTreeNode(newNode)
            return True
    else:
        if self.right_child:
            return self.right_child.insert_node(newNode)
        else:
            self.right_child = BinaryTreeNode(newNode)
            return True
```

With those 3 fixes applied, the code finally outputs the expected indented display.

Comment: You forgot to mention that right childs never inserted

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov: ah, `BinaryTreeNode.insert_node` does in deed look incomplete. There may be a part missing there.

Comment: Ah! I didn't even catch that, thanks! I made those changes and I'm still receiving a TypeError: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Programming Projects/BinaryTree.py", line 46, in <module>
    tree.insert(5)
  File "G:/Programming Projects/BinaryTree.py", line 38, in insert
    self.root = BinaryTree(k)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: `BinaryTree` != `BinaryTreeNode` The code you posted in your question does not have that error.

Comment: I see the mistakes. I was also using `return self.root.insert(k)` instead of `self.insert_node(k)`. Thank you for your assistance. The code works flawlessly now!